# placeholder in termcolor python

Tags: python, cs50

I'm working on sentiments challenge for CS50 and I want to print in the console with color using Termcolor and placeholders but I have some problem.

This is my code:

```
    if score > 0:
        green = lambda x: colored(x, 'green')
        print(green("1 ", tweets))
    elif score < 0:
        red = lambda x: colored(x, 'red')
        print(red(tweets))
    else:
        yellow = lambda x: colored(x, 'yellow')
        print(yellow(tweets))
```

I want to print the tweet based on the score (green, red or yellow) and that's ok, the code works well with lambda x, but I want also to print a number before the tweet in the same color.

I've tried lambda x, y but I have an error:

```
if score > 0:
   green = lambda x, y: colored(x, y, 'green')
   print(green("1 ", tweets))


Traceback (most recent call last):
File "./tweets", line 47, in <module>
  main()
File "./tweets", line 39, in main
  print(green("1 ", tweets))
File "./tweets", line 38, in <lambda>
  green = lambda x, y: colored(x, y, 'green')
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/termcolor.py", line 105, in colored
text = fmt_str % (COLORS[color], text)
  KeyError: 'Building Augmented Reality Experiences with Unity3D (and @Microsoft @HoloLens)  by @shekitup at @CS50 at @Harvard,'
```

This is what I want to print:

```
1 + (tweets) in green if positive
-1 + (tweets) in red if negative
0 + (tweets) in yellow if neutral
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a subtask and call it too:

```
def show_tweets_by_color(num, col, tweets):
  green = lambda x: colored(x, 'green')
  print(colored(str(num), " green") + green(tweets))


if score > 0:
    show_tweets_by_color(1, "green", tweets)
...
```

Comment: I've already tried something like this, with your solution I have an error: Too many positional arguments for lambda call

Comment: @Sebastiano I make an edit, let me know if that works

Comment: nop, but i find a solution: print(colored("1 ", "green") + green(tweets)) maybe there is a way more easiest

Comment: @Sebastiano yes, fantastic, that's a posible way, I edited the answer with another posibilitie, and don't forget to mark one answer as accepted (left top check box in the answer :) )

Comment: it's a good solution, to be more flexible you can change the "green" with "col" and in this way, you can use the same function for negative positive and neutral :) good.

Answer (score 1):

does this way makes sense with your code ?

(This syntax works only for python >= 3.5, unpacked parameters should be the last to avoid ambiguity in prior versions)

```
if score > 0:
   green = lambda x: colored(*x, 'green')
   print(green(["1 ", tweets]))
```

You pass a list of parameter, tweet alone, or number and tweet, and then it's unpack in the lambda

Comment: In this way I have an error: SyntaxError: only named arguments may follow *expression

Comment: @sebastiano, i'm curious about reproduce this, what version of python are you using ?

Comment: Python 3 in Cloud9 with the CS50 IDE

Comment: @sebastiano ok thanks, looks like this syntax doesnt work for version before 3.5

Comment: @PRMoureu if you edit the answer with this clarify, the answer is good! Plus one

Comment: @PRMoureu yes no problem! Another less tricky way is create another function, as my example bellow :), check it if you want

Comment: it still doesn't work :( this is the link to the instruction, they put python 3 but i don't know how to check the exact version.
http://docs.cs50.net/problems/sentiments/sentiments.html#walkthrough

Comment: @sebastiano `import sys`, `print(sys.version)`

Comment: 3.4.3 (default, Nov 17 2016, 01:08:31) 
[GCC 4.8.4]

Comment: so stay with Damian's solution ;-)